# Who wrote the alien words in Agents of Shield episode 4?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, agents-of-shield

I am a very big fan of the Marvel Universe because every time it sticks in my mind and forces me to explore. This time I am stuck with the actions of Agent Ward in Season 1, Episode 4 of *Agents of Shield*.

In that episode, Agent Ward goes to some secret facility to take a snapshot of an alien language. Only those who have taken the drug G.H. can write it, and we also know that only two persons have that drug inside them. And one of them got that drug at the last.

So my questions are: who wrote the language in that facility? Does anyone else have the drug too, because according to SHIELD only few people know about it. And according to Lady Sif no such alien has come to Earth, so where could the language in the facility have come from?

Comment: Can you edit this to clarify your question?

Comment: Well Sif COULD be wrong about such things, after all, she basically states that other than the frost giants, none of the blue-skinned aliens she mentioned ever visited the Earth, when Phil asks her about them, yet, watching Guardians, Yondu looks fairly blue to me.....

Comment: I don't think "Only those who have taken the drug G.H. can write it" is correct. There is an entire alien race somewhere who read and write those glyphs. Just because Sif didn't know of visits doesn't mean there haven't been any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More than two people went received GH325.  When Coulson was overseeing T.A.H.I.T.I. they put some people through the process.  This then resulted in the video where Coulson recommends the process is never used.  So the early test subjects would have been dosed with GH325, and one of them may be who wrote the alien language in the facility.

Comment: I can this could be the reason, Thank you @Keen. But what you think where are those subjects? Are they free now or Dead?